# Two activities, one sqlopenhelper

Tags: android, android-listview

I have one sqliteopenhelper (extended) object that I am using to display data in one activity

In another activity, I have an 'onclick' method where I want to add data

(the two activities are connected by buttons - add item / save item)

My question is - should the two activities have their own sqlopenhelper object?
Or, should they share the same one?

Also - 
When the user returns to the first activity screen after adding an item, will the adapter automatically show the new item in the list?
Or, does *notifyDataSetChanged* have to be called?

Comment: **"My question is - should the two activities have their own sqlopenhelper object?"** - No. Extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a singleton. **"does notifyDataSetChanged have to be called?"** - Yes.

Comment: +1 the openhelper sould be a singleton. You could use the application instance to share it between your activities or create a static class your self so you can access it everywhere

Comment: Thanks for that. I now have another question. Where do you call notifyDataSetChanged? Do you add it to the onresume method of the list activity, so it is called each time the user navigates to the list? Or, should it be called from the activity that modifies the data? I would not be sure how to do that, as the adapter object belongs to the list activity, not to the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct,

- You have to create two different Object and initialize that in different activity to access `SQLiteDatabaseHelper`
- Use `notifyDataSetChanged` while add data in the list.
- [See Reference example here](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/) in that you will get complete idea to implement.